# Executing a jar file in PHP

Tags: java, php, terminal, server

This is my directory on my file server: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADMC1.png, what I want is to navigate to run_conversion.php and have that script run iRS_Converter.jar which will convert client_img.jpg and create a new file.

This is what my php script looks like:

```
<?php 
exec("java -jar iRS_Converter.jar"); 
?>
```

But when I navigate to the script in browser, it does nothing. How do I get it to run my jar file? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Check if working directory is OK: `echo BACKQUOTEpwdBACKQUOTE`  
2) Check the command in terminal
3) Check does current user have permissions to change files in the directory

Comment: Something that I thought of while reading your post is; I am attempting to run the jar on a file server running centos, and it probably doesn't have java installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you get your command running via ssh you probably have to change the working directory inside your php script. Try this:

```
chdir(__DIR__);
```

(This sets the working dir to the directory of your php file. If you don't want that replace the `__DIR__` with whatever your working dir should be)

If you don't host the files yourself (on a virtual server, etc.) then there is probably no java installed. To check if java is installed try:

```
echo shell_exec("which java");
```

If the result is empty then java is not installed. If it is something like `/usr/bin/java` then it's available.